# Why does $1 - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\dots$ converge to $e^{-x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

The series

$$
1 - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\dots=e^{-x}
$$

It is not totally clear from (for example) limits like

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}( 1 - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2) = \infty \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}( 1 - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^3) = -\infty \\
\vdots
$$
why the sum to infinity has a limit of 0. What is "happening" after each partial sum diverges? I suppose the remaining part of the series diverges in the other direction in just the right way that we end up with facts like
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}( e^{-x}) = 0
$$
but this is not always true just from the oscillating infinities.

The reason this is important is that there should/might be a general condition for a oscillating power series to have a limit of $0$, of which this is a simple example. But how does even this simple case have limit $0$, without first seeing that the series is $e^{-x}$?

Comment: It is the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=e^{-x}$

Comment: Obviously its $e^{-x}$, but if you work backwards from the series to the exponential, how does that work?

Comment: This is an example of limits not always being interchangeable. Calling the partial power series $P_n(x)$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}P_n(x) = \infty$ while $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P_n(x) =0$.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$? For some people, the definition is the Taylor series, in which case the result is immediate.

Comment: So is oscillating $\infty$ and $-\infty$ enough to get 0?

Comment: Based on my understanding of the question, you would like to prove that 

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!} = 0
\end{align}

Without knowing that the serie is indeed equal to $e^{-x}$. Is that true?

Comment: @Youem Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: The question you're asking fundamentally relates to swapping limit processes. This can't always be done, and this is one such case.

Comment: Hint: use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: Note that it converges uniformly on any compact set.

Comment: Naively, every time you add another term you add another zero to the polynomial. This means every term creates additional oscillations since the graph must pass through zero an additional time. It's not strictly true but it provides some intuition as to why this can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a simple procedure for establishing if
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n a_n x^n $$
equals zero or not, provided that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a non-negative sequence convergent to zero rapidly enough to make the function entire. For instance, in the case $a_n = \frac{1}{n!^2}$ we have

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n a_n x^n = O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}}\right)\quad\text{as }x\to +\infty\tag{1} $$
which looks pretty non-trivial to me. Such things (like Tricomi's inequality hidden in $(1)$) are usually proved by exploiting the fact that the structure of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ makes the generating function a solution of a reasonably simple differential equation. For instance, by defining
$$ \sinh(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$
$$ \cosh(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} $$
we have
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)\right) $$
and the structure of $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ gives the nice identity $\cosh^2(x)=1+\sinh^2(x)$ reminiscent of the Pythagorean theorem. That also gives that the previous limit equals

$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}-\sinh(x)\right)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh(x)+\cosh(x)} $$
and now this is *blatantly zero* since both $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ are increasing and unbounded over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{^n}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$
converges absolutely in $\mathbb{R}$, by the ratio test, so we can denote
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$
Now, absolute convergence allows as to conclude that the Cauchy product of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ converges to $f(x)f(y)$, and their Cauchy product is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \left((-1)^{k}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left( (-1)^{n-k}\dfrac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \right) \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^n y^{n-k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{(x+y)^n}{n!} = f(x+y)$$

So, we have prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and letting $y=-x$ we get that
$$f(x)f(-x)=f(0)=1$$
and so
$$f(-x)=\dfrac{1}{f(x)} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(-x)= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{1}{f(x)}$$
and is enough to see that
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$

But, for any $x<0$ we have that
$$f(x)=f(-|x|) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{(-|x|)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{|x|^n}{n!} \geq 1+|x|$$
and as
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} 1+ |x|=+\infty$$
we get the desired result.

Comment: (+1) Nicely written.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $P_n(x)$ the polynomial function made of partial sums

$$
P_0(x) = 1
$$
$$
P_1(x) = 1-x
$$
$$
P_2(x) = 1-x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
P_{n}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \dfrac{(-1)^i}{i!} \cdot x^{i}
$$

The infinite series in a domain $D$ using the partial polynomials normally is defined by the limit

$$
P(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P_{n}(x) \ \ \ \forall x \in D
$$

And when you do a limit $x \to \infty$ of $P(x)$ you are computing
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} P(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} P_{n}(x) \overset{?}{=} \lim_{x \to \infty \\ n \to \infty} P_{n}(x) \overset{?}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to \infty} P_{n}(x) 
$$

In this example you are taking the limit of two variables and rearranging they as you want. Depending on your choice of path, the limit of two variables doesn't converge and the 'notion' of series is not the same anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the proof is simpler than it seems. We write

$1-x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{3!}x^{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{n!}x^{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{1}{k!}x^{k}-e^{-x}$

and now we use Taylor's theorem with a remainder for $e^{-x}$=$1-x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{3!}x^{3}+...+(-1)^{n}\dfrac{1}{n!}x^{n}$$+(+/-)$$\dfrac{e^{-\xi}}{(n+1)!}$$x^{n+1}$. After subtracting we are left with

$\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{1}{k!}x^{k}$+$(+/-)\dfrac{e^{-\xi}}{(n+1)!}$$x^{n+1}$. It is well known that $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ $\to 0$ and clearly

$\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{1}{k!}x^{k}$ $\to 0$ since the series is convergent.
So on any closed bounded set $B$ such that $x\in B$ we have uniform convergence, and the result is proved!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question "is alternating  between $\infty$ and $-\infty$ is enough to say that the limit of the series will be $0$"? is **NO**.

It works for the $e^{-x}$ series. But it does not work for $\sin (x)$ for example.

Comment: That is basically me clarifying "what, then, is the condition that makes the limit of this sum go to zero?" (i.e. Its relatively clear that oscillating infinities leads to inconclusive results). Are there other examples of sums with that property? The OP's question is basically to show (with just reversing a Taylor series argument) why the sum converges to $e^{-x}$.

Comment: In my knowledge I am not aware of any condition that makes thing work always. However since the series is alternating the sum will always be bounded.

Comment: Why is it always bounded? Is that a theorem? I think I saw that somewhere in a metric space course.

Comment: (above it should say "without just reversing...")

Comment: The sum of an alternate serie is always smaller than the first term if the absolute value of $a_n$ is non increasing.

Comment: But if the terms are increasing in magnitude, but still sum to zero? Then the partial sums are bounds (e.g. Bonferroni inequalities)